# Accessing Object properties in a loop

Tags: c#, object, properties

Is it better to assign a object property to a variable first instead of using it directly in a loop?

Say I have a bitmap `Bitmap img = new Bitmap("image.jpg")` and I needed to loop through all the pixels to do some processing.  For a 1080p image that's about 2 million pixels.  Does it matter if I use `data.Stride` or assign them to a variable first `int dataStride = data.Stride`? I need to access it each time to calculate the offset but the dataStride is a constant of the image.

```
data = editImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, editWidth, editHeight), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
byte* dataPtr = (byte*)data.Scan0;
dataStride = data.Stride;
```

I assign them to a variable first since I am thinking that it has to access the object (each time) first and then access the integer from the object (each time) which is slower.  And since it is a large loop... it adds up.  So assigning the property to a variable first will be faster since it can access the int value directly.  Is this correct?

Comment: Write it both ways and measure performance over multiple runs in release mode, either with System.Diagnostics.StopWatch or a Profiler. There are a lot of corner cases where one or the other may be faster, and unless someone actually measured it against a byte pointer, general purpose information isn't going to be that helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  No matter how simple the property, accessing it still has the overhead of a function call.  A variable is faster, especially if you are doing something 2 million times.

Comment: I agree with @lukas, compiler and CLR are by far optimized to do the trick (even if you can also help a little by using a local @Ryder).

Comment: Yes and no. When looping over an array, the JITter can and usually disable the bounds checking - `for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` is faster than `x = arr.Length; for(i = 0; i < x; i++)`. However, for properties, this may or may not be the case. If it's simple a field-getter, it may be inlined, but if it's a real method (and I know GDI has some of them), then it can get real expensive. For example, Image.Width is a call to GDI+, so `for(int i = 0; i<image.Width;i++)` is ridiculously expensive.

Comment: @MichaelStum I did `for(int i = 0; i<image.Width;i++)` before and then changed it to `int width = image.Width; for(int i = 0; i<width;i++)` and noticed an improvement in speed which is why I thought assigning them to variables first was faster.  I ended up doing that for most of my loops... but wasn't sure if that was the case in general.

Comment: In general though, you don't know if the `getter` if the property is doing more processing. In this case you can find out by checking the code behind Bitmap, but what if someone wrote: `public string MyProperty { get { Thread.Sleep(100); return "slow?"; } }` Yes that person should be shot, but I have seen apps where property getters read from settings files off a disk, or find a field in XML... IMO copying what you need to a local variable is safer when dealing with outside / 3rd party code.

Comment: @rally25rs But why is `for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` faster than `x = arr.Length; for(i = 0; i < x; i++)`?

Comment: @Ryder because .net knows it's an array, it does something special (I haven't checked exactly what, I think it doesn't actually have to check if the end of the array is reached since it knows the length, but again, haven't checked). That's a really minor optimization though. In general, declaring a variable is usually safe, but also usually not required and bloats your code. Measuring is really the only way to get certainty.

Comment: See this article by Jon Skeet for some interesting bits: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/29/for-vs-foreach-on-arrays-and-lists.aspx

Comment: Yeah, .NET knows to do something different with `Array.Length`. If instead you make your own class with a property: `public int Length { get { return 100000000; } }` then it gets really slow compared to looping over `myObj.Length` versus copying it to a local variable. So I guess the answer is "testing is the only way to know" or, more generally, use properties with System types, and local variables with non-System types? ... and I bet you thought this question would have an easy answer :)